# how does "getManager().query()" work in TypeORM?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

i'm learning TypeORM now and i can't really understand 'query' method, how it works.

Example code is like below.

```
    export const lists = async (
      roleFilter: RoleFilter,
      filter: Filter,
      dateFilter: BetweenDate,
    ) => {
      const carLists = await getCars(roleFilter, filter);
      if (carLists.length === 0) {
        return { totalCount: 0, lists: [] };
      }
      const carIds = carLists.map(car => car.id); // **2 여기서 아이디만 가져옴

      const isCheckParam: number[] = [];
      let isCheckSQL = '';

      if (filter.isCheck !== null) {
      ....
      }

      const typeParamArray: string[] = [];
      const typeSQLArray: string[] = [];
      if (filter.impact === 1) {
        typeParamArray.push('impact');
        typeSQLArray.push('car_alarm.type = ?');
      }
      ....

      const typeSQL =
        typeSQLArray.length === 0 ? '' : `(${typeSQLArray.join(' OR ')}) AND`;

      const countQuery = `
        SELECT
          count(*) AS cnt
        FROM
          car_alarm
        WHERE ${typeSQL} ${isCheckSQL} car_alarm.carId IN (?) AND DATE(alarmAt) BETWEEN ? AND ?

      const countQuery = `
        SELECT
      count(*) AS cnt
    FROM
      car_alarm
    WHERE ${typeSQL} ${isCheckSQL} car_alarm.carId IN (?) AND DATE(alarmAt) BETWEEN ? AND ?
  `;

  const countResult = await getManager().query(countQuery, [
    ...typeParamArray,
    ...isCheckParam,
    carIds,
    dateFilter.start,
    dateFilter.end
  ]);
```

In this part getManager().query() is used.

```
  const countResult = await getManager().query(countQuery, [
    ...typeParamArray,
    ...isCheckParam,
    carIds,
    dateFilter.start,
    dateFilter.end
  ]);
```

could someone explain me how 'query()' works? somehow i can't find any example or explain about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `query()` method executes a raw parameterized sql query, so you have to write a sql query specific to the database you are using. The second argument of `query()` is an array of parameters for the SQL query, which are [substituted](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) within the sql query.

For executing raw sql queries no TypeORM is needed, therefore any database driver package (e.g. [mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), [pg](https://node-postgres.com/)) can be used. The advantage of using TypeORM is that queries are created automatically and mapped to entity objects.